# Access a DB name dynamically

Tags: sql

Can we access a table of one database from other databases on the same server?
Like :

```
select * from [db1].dbo.[customer];
where db1 is my databasename 
customer is table name.
```

I want [db1] to take from any object (function etc) where I can set the db name whatever i need.

Comment: Please add your DBMS (Sql Server, Oracle, MySql....)

Comment: Yes, you can access a table in another database on the same server.